# $G\times H\cong G$ with $H$ non-trivial

Tags: group-theory

Aluffi II.3.4 asks the reader to find groups $G$ and $H$ such that $G\times H\cong G$ but $H$ is not trivial. I believe I have found a solution, but would like someone to check. Also, is there a more elementary example? I tried mucking around with $S^1\times (\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)$, which feels like it should be isomorphic to $S^1$ (the unit circle under complex multiplication), but I kept getting confused.

#### My solution

Let $H$ be a non-trivial group and let $G=H^\omega$. Then $\phi\colon H\times G\to G$ defined by
$$\phi(h,g)_n=\begin{cases}
h &n=0\\
g_{n-1} &n\ne 0
\end{cases}$$
looks like a group isomorphism to me. It's obviously a bijective function, and \begin{align*}
\phi((h_1,g_1)(h_2,g_2))_n
&=\phi(h_1h_2,g_1g_2)_n \\
&=\begin{cases}
h_1h_2&n=0\\
(g_1g_2)_{n-1}&n\ne 0
\end{cases}\\
&=\phi(h_1,g_1)_n\phi(h_2,g_2)_n \\
&=(\phi(h_1,g_1)\phi(h_2,g_2))_n.
\end{align*}

Comment: Yes. It would be better to define $H^\omega$, but that's fine.

Comment: Even easier: if $G=H^\omega$, then clearly $G\times G\cong G$ via any bijection between $\omega\times\omega$ and $\omega$.

Comment: Note, you can use $H^{<\omega}$.

Comment: Stupid question, but what is $\omega$ in this case?

Comment: Usually, used for the ordinal of natural numbers. @Luis

Comment: But OP might mean $H^{\omega}$ to mean the direct limit of $H^n$ for $n$ runs over the ordinal, in which case, that was what I meant by $H^{<\omega}$. I've forgotten too much notation.

Comment: As a side note, $S^1$ is not isomorphic to $S^1 \times \left(\mathbb{Z} / 2\mathbb{Z}\right)$.  The former has a unique element of order $2$, the latter has $3$ such elements.

Comment: What I meant was the ordinal of the natural numbers. Perhaps $\times^{(\omega)} H$ would have been clearer?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, is the point you're getting at that *any* case where $A\subsetneqq B$ but $|A|=|B|$ will produce an example of this form? My example is the simplest instance of $\alpha+\beta=\beta$ when $\alpha<\beta$. I guess I could have simplified things by generalizing a drop.

Comment: My point is simply that if you know that $|\omega\times\omega|=\omega$, then $H^\omega\times H^\omega\cong H^\omega$ is a zero-work example.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, I may well be dense, but I don't understand that. $H^\omega\times H^\omega=H^{\omega+\omega}$, so this seems to involve $|\omega+\omega|=|\omega|$, right? Or am I missing something important?

Comment: Yes, both times when I wrote $\omega\times\omega$ I meant $\omega+\omega$.

Answer (score 2):

A simple example would be the natural numbers (including zero) under the operation "bitwise exclusive or." This is isomorphic to $$G=\oplus_{i=0}^{\infty} \mathbb Z/\langle 2\rangle$$

Comment: I don't know what $\oplus$ means yet, but this is sounding kind of like the $\Bbb Z_2^{<\omega}$ example, I think?

Comment: Yes, same example. @dfeuer